# post value is not inserting in dynamic generted row in php form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

i have small php form (with dynamic generated input rows) where i need one value from previous form. that value successfully inserted in first row. but when i dynamically generate more rows than that value is not automatically insert in that rows.

here is previous form post value

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $id1 = $_POST['id1'];
        $company = $_POST['company'];
      **  $empid = $_POST['empid'];**
        $empname = $_POST['empname'];
}
```

and this is my new form where i want that empid should automatically insert in all rows.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-success" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
        <tr>
            <th><center>Empid</th>
            <th><center>Subject</th>
            <th>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                    onclick="BtnAdd()"
                >
                    Add Item
                </button>                         
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TBody">
        <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
            <td>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="empid[]"
                    id="empid"
                    value="<?php echo $empid; ?>"
                    class="zzz1 form-control text-end"
                >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="subject[]"
                    id="subject"
                    class="state form-control text-end"
                    required
                >
            </td>
            <td class="NoPrint">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                    style="line-height: 1;"
                    onclick="BtnDel(this)"
                >
                    x
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is javascript code to generate rows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetPrint()
{
    /*For Print*/
    window.print();
}

function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).find("input").autocomplete({
        source: 'backend-script.php'  
    });
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /*Delete Button*/
    $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
    GetTotal();

    $("#TBody").find("tr").each(function(index) {
        $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
    });
}
```

Comment: If you want others to help you and to find bugs in your code more easily, make sure you properly indent your code first.

Comment: @Anax ok i will

Comment: @ADyson i tried following but it duplicate all data from first row instead of just emp id  ~~~  let ip = $(v).find("input"); 
  ip.val(ip.prop($empid));~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by asking it not to clear the empID from the fields when you clear all the other fields in the newly cloned row:

```
$(v).find("input:not(input[name='empid[]'])").val('');
```

Demo:

```js
function GetPrint()
{
    /*For Print*/
    window.print();
}

function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody");
    $(v).find("input:not(input[name='empid[]'])").val('');
    $(v).find("input").autocomplete({
        source: 'backend-script.php'  
    });
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /*Delete Button*/
    $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
    GetTotal();

    $("#TBody").find("tr").each(function(index) {
        $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-success" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
        <tr>
            <th>Empid</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                    onclick="BtnAdd()"
                >
                    Add Item
                </button>                         
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TBody">
        <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
            <td>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="empid[]"
                    value="123"
                    class="zzz1 form-control text-end"
                >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="subject[]"
                    id="subject"
                    class="state form-control text-end"
                    required
                >
            </td>
            <td class="NoPrint">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                    style="line-height: 1;"
                    onclick="BtnDel(this)"
                >
                    x
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```